# using regex for image domains in NextJS next.config.js

Tags: javascript, regex, next.js

does regex work in next.config.js for image domains? Looks like giphy uses different numbers for its endpoints (e.g. media0.giphy.com, media2.giphy.com) but regex isn't working so I'm getting this error: `hostname "media0.giphy.com" is not configured under images in your next.config.js`. If not, is there a good way to handle this?

`next.config.js`:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    dangerouslyAllowSVG: true,
    domains: ["media\\d.giphy.com"],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `domains` don't support regex. Use [remotePatterns](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#remote-patterns) which support glob (similar to regex).

[Domains](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#domains)

> Similar to remotePatterns, the domains configuration can be used to provide a list of allowed hostnames for external images.

> However, the domains configuration does not support wildcard pattern matching and it cannot restrict protocol, port, or pathname.

> Note: We recommend using remotePatterns instead so you can restrict protocol and pathname.

Comment: `remotePatterns` exists [since v12.3.0](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v12.3.0). It was [first introduced in v12.2.0](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2#remote-patterns-experimental) as an experimental feature.